# Only One or Two keys working on keyboard

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure

I recently spilt Tea on a laptop. Everything was OK, but the keyboard. It worked but had a few sticky keys that weren't working, so I rinsed the keyboard in lukewarm water and left it for 24 hours. When I put the keyboard back in, It worked for 10 minutes, then it became totally unresponsive. I have rebooted a few times and each time only the n or sometimes j keys work. I want to know if it is the keyboard that's the problem, or the computer, as I don't want to waste my money on a new computer for no reason. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, the caps lock light doesn't come on.

Comment: it's the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I expect that the keyboard was not completely dry before you put it back in. As you typed you caused the water to move around and short something out. If you are lucky the short is in the keyboard. If not, you may have damaged the laptop.

You may be able to salvage it. Turn off the power, unplug the battery and power supply right away. Remove the keyboard and leave it in a warm place - a sunny window would do nicely - for a day or too. Leave the laptop there also. Let it dry out really well. Be patient. Then put everything back together and see if it works.

If this doesn't work, replace the keyboard. I recommend going to a shop that can try installing a new keyboard for you. If it doesn't work then you have damaged the laptop itself. That would be unfortunate, but at least you will be at the repair shop.